# Avoid UIButton overlay on UIPickerView ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uipickerview

I am started to learn iOS. I am doing small app. In that I placed `UIPickerView` and `UIButton` in ViewController. On view controller tap, `UIPickerView` will show to the user. On showing, the detail, `UIButton` also show (overlay on `UIPickerView`). How can I Put the `UIButton` back to viewController.

How to avoid inappropriate view.?

See the `update button` in `UIPicker view`

[image]

Comment: Present UIPickerview in ActionSheet.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

this depends on the order you add your subviews to your view. try `[viewController.view sendSubviewToBack: yourButton]`

in interface builder drag the view you want to place on top of your view hierarchie to the bottom. on the picture `UISegmentedControl` would overlap the `UIButton` if not properly aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your xib file and drag your `Picker` object to the bottom of its container as in the image below:

[image]